# file download popup box using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, download

I am working on ASP.NET web form application.
I am processing file at server side in my web service code.
This web method will return me file memory stream.
I would like to consume this memory stream at client side using javascript method.
after processing in js method i will open popup to download that memory stream.

```
function ExportExel(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl + '/' + "WebServices/ExtraInfoWebService.asmx/Urlhttphandler",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {

            //********some code require here.... *************
        }
    });
}
```

in msg.d i am getting memory stream
i need code here

```
//********some code require here.... *************
```

to show file download popup.
Any help/pointers will be helpful for me.

Comment: Why you don't just redirect to download page? In case it has special headers forcing the download, your page will not be actually changed, instead of that download will start.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can i redirect to my download page from javascript function? small code snippet will work for me to understand.

Comment: Simply do: 
location.href = "downloadable/file/url.php";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you will need to give `new request` to server..
`Ajax` call does not provide that much facility (showing popup when get stream)
If you send new request and response get in the form of stream. browser shows the `save and open popup`. you don't need to do it manually

Comment: How can i send new request to server? instead of  Ajax call any other you suggest. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: use $('#'+form_id).attr('action',new_url_action); $("#form_id").submit(); in javascript insead of $.ajax and before submit you can do your form validations if having form fields

Comment: $('#'+form_id).attr('action',new_url_action); $("#form_id").submit(); this works but it opens window in same browser's page. any other parameter to pass or method to avoid this

Comment: `target="_blank"` attribute is there for form. it will open window in new tab. hope it will be useful